# Can't update hardcoded data in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've tried to update a single email inside object of user as following,
for some reason after I manipulate and change the readMessage status to either true/false, the changes doesn't save. Anyone can explain me what am I doing wrong?

This is the hardcoded database:

```
               public class InMemoryUsersData
    {
        //hardcoded database
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }

        public InMemoryUsersData()
        {
            Users = new List<User>()
            {
                new User
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    FirstName = "Jonathan",
                    LastName = "Darmon",
                    Email = "darmon101@gmail.com",
                    Password = "1234",
                    ListOfEmails = new List<Email>()
                    {
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 1,
                            Title = "Hello",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            Title = "Hey there",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 3,
                            Title = "Subject",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                         new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 4,
                            Title = "GDSGSD",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor amet, adipiscing.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                         new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 5,
                            Title = "Test",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor, adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        }
                    }
                },
                new User
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    FirstName = "Test2",
                    LastName = "Test2",
                    Email = "test2@gmail.com",
                    Password = "test2",
                      ListOfEmails = new List<Email>()
                    {
                         new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            Title = "Hello",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 5,
                            Title = "Hey there",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 6,
                            Title = "Subject",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                         new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 8,
                            Title = "GDSGSD",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor  amet,  adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        }
                    }
                },
                 new User
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    FirstName = "Test3",
                    LastName = "Test3",
                    Email = "test3@gmail.com",
                    Password = "test3",
                      ListOfEmails = new List<Email>()
                    {
                         new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 6,
                            Title = "Test125",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 8,
                            Title = "Hey there",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 9,
                            Title = "Subject",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        }
                    }
                },
                  new User
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    FirstName = "Test4",
                    LastName = "Test4",
                    Email = "test4@gmail.com",
                    Password = "test4",
                      ListOfEmails = new List<Email>()
                    {
                         new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 1,
                            Title = "Test123513512325",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            Title = "Hey thereeeeeeeeeeee",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 3,
                            Title = "Subject",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        }
                    }
                },
                   new User
                {
                    Id = 5,
                    FirstName = "Test5",
                    LastName = "Test5",
                    Email = "test5@gmail.com",
                    Password = "test5",
                      ListOfEmails = new List<Email>()
                    {
                         new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 1,
                            Title = "Test5Test5Test5Test5Test5Test5",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            Title = "Hey there",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        },
                        new Email()
                        {
                            Id = 3,
                            Title = "Subject",
                            BodyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                            MessageDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ReadMessage = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

This is the repository which manipulate on the object:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly InMemoryUsersData _data;

        public UserRepository()
        {
            _data = new InMemoryUsersData();
        }


        public async Task<User> GetUser(int id)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_data.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
        }

        public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
        {
            List<User> dataResponse = _data.Users;

            return await Task.FromResult(dataResponse);
        }

        public async Task<List<Email>> GetListOfMessagesByUser(int id)
        {
            var userResponse = await Task.FromResult(_data.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
            if (userResponse == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(userResponse.ListOfEmails);
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<Email>> UpdateMessage(int id, int messageId)
        {
            var user = await Task.FromResult(_data.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
            if (user != null)
            {
                var email = user.ListOfEmails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == messageId);
                if (email.ReadMessage == true)
                {
                    email.ReadMessage = false;
                    return user.ListOfEmails;
                }
                else
                {
                    email.ReadMessage = true;
                    return user.ListOfEmails;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public async Task<User> Authenticate(string email, string password)
        {
            User user = await Task.FromResult(_data.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == password));
            if (user == null)
                return null;

            return await Task.FromResult(user);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using EF? Are you calling SaveChanges()?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what do you mean by "the changes doesn't save"? How do you detect that?

Comment: @thomai No, I don't use Entity Framework at the moment, just simple hardcoded database as you can see. This instance is inside the constructor and the core which does the manipulation is located in the repository.

Comment: @Marchyello api request with postman, I recieve the following list as you can see. Then after I do the updateMessage method the response shows the data has changed, but once I call the GetAllMessages the data shows as it is without any changes.

Comment: This is just a speculation, but if your hardcoded database is not declared statically/is not a singleton (i.e., it is re-initiated on every call), the updates that you make in your `UpdateMessage` method do not persist when you call the `GetAllMessages` method later. Could you elaborate on the life cycle of your database?

Comment: @Marchyello I added to my question the full classes, I think I got your point which I create a new instance each time I make an api call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you encounter this problem I already guessed in my comment.

The simplest/quickest way you can fix this is - just register your `IUserRepository` service as a singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

In that case it will be initialized only once meaning your `UserRepository` construcor will not repeatedly overwrite your dabase and your changes will persist between calls.

Comment: Thank you very much for notifying me. I wouldn't see that even in a year :D
It is working perfectly now. I changed it from AddTransient<> to AddSingleton<> just like you said

Comment: @Darmon Happy to help. Just another thing concerning your code - there is no reason to use `async/await` and `Task` here. These methods are not asynchronous. This is not an issue per se, just redundant and a bit confusing.

Comment: Fiddling around with Lists from multiple threads is everything but safe...

Comment: @Tseng When I see things like a hardcoded "database" my spider sense tells me the code that runs it is nowhere near production. Therefore I assume no concurrent requests are made and thread safety is of no concern.

Comment: @Marchyello Yeah, its just practice and nothing close to production. I am trying different approaches in order to understand better the design patterns. Btw, even if this methods used by api's controllers I shouldn't use async/await and Task?

Comment: @Marchyello: Even if so: There are other people who stumble over this question and blindly copy the content w/o thinking lol. SO isn't a private Q/A show

Comment: @Darmon There's a lot more to it than this (and you should do yourself a favour and read up on it), but at the highest level `Task<TResult>` serves just as a wrapper which denotes that *eventually* an object/value of type `TResult` will become awailable. You unwrap it by `await`ing it. In your code stuff like `await Task.FromResult(user);` just wraps/unwraps `user` immediately, which serves no purpose. The fact that an API endpoint calls this method makes no difference.